# pybind11 - Making STL container std::list into an opaque type?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

pybind11 provides [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#binding-stl-containers) for making `std::vector` and `std::map` types opaque, but doesn't say anything about making a `std::list` opaque.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Note: In general you *don't* want to use linked lists at all. They are close to the worst performing data structure on modern systems you can pick.

Comment: I understand that. However, I'm binding existing C++ code that I'm not able to change.